# Select current week, starts from Monday instead of Sunday

Tags: mysql, sql

I've managed to select the data from the current week but the week itself starts from Sunday which is not the right format for me, it should starts from Monday. I'm using MySQL to query the data.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rendeles_dbszam),0) as eladott_pizzak_szama 
  FROM rendeles 
 WHERE WEEK(rendeles_idopont) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: The difference between a week that starts on a Sunday and one that starts on a Monday is a single day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this little formula to get the Monday starting the week of any given DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP object.

```
FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -MOD(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -2, 7))
```

I like to use it in a stored function named `TRUNC_MONDAY(datestamp)` defined like this.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS TRUNC_MONDAY$$
CREATE
  FUNCTION TRUNC_MONDAY(datestamp DATETIME)
  RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
  COMMENT 'preceding Monday'
  RETURN FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -MOD(TO_DAYS(datestamp) -2, 7))$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can do stuff like this

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rendeles_dbszam),0) as eladott_pizzak_szama
  FROM rendeles
 WHERE TRUNC_MONDAY(rendeles_idopont) = TRUNC_MONDAY(CURRENT_DATE())
```

or even this to get a report covering eight previous weeks and the current week.

```
SELECT SUM(rendeles_dbszam) as eladott_pizzak_szama,
       TRUNC_MONDAY(rendeles_idopont) as week_beginning
  FROM rendeles
 WHERE rendeles_idopont >= TRUNC_MONDAY(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 8 WEEK
   AND rendeles_idopoint < TRUNC_MONDAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
 GROUP BY TRUNC_MONDAY(rendeles_idopont)
```

I particularly like this `TRUNC_MONDAY()` approach because it works unambiguously even for calendar weeks that contain New Years' Days.

(If you want `TRUNC_SUNDAY()` change the `-2` in the formula to `-1`.)

Comment: Sorry to say I cannot read and write Magyar, so the names in my examples are probably nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

'Week' in mysql has 2 inputs: date and week type. By default it's equal 0. That means week starts from sunday. Try this code:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rendeles_dbszam),0) as eladott_pizzak_szama FROM rendeles WHERE WEEK(rendeles_idopont) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE(),1)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if its right, because i'm still geting the values from sunday. I only have orders from this saturday and sunday so i should get 0 values this way right?